# Expand Ansible role with tasks without modifying the role itself

Tags: git, ansible

I have lots of Ansible roles which got copied from project to project so I've decided to store the roles in a separate Git repositories and assemble the playbook using Git submodules.

The desired playbook structure is:

```
- Playbook repo
  - playbook.yml
  - roles/role1 (submodule)
  - roles/role2 (submodule)
  - roles/role3 (playbook-specific role)
```

The problem is that sometimes it's not worth to commit the extra functions into the role repository (long code review process, the functionality is too specific, etc.) so I need a way to expand the role steps without modifying the role itself like:

```
---

- name: Deploy the product and the very-specific-configuration
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
      tasks:
        - name: extra_specific_task1
          command: '<some_command>'
          become: True
        - name: extra_specific_task2
          package:
            name: '<pkgname>'
            state: present
          become: True
    - role3
```

So the question is: How to add such kind of function?

Comment: It's flexible tool and IMHO there is no such policy that you are looking for. [Module include_role and parameter tasks_from](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html)  allow you to create large variety of combinations. It's good idea to start with well-defined roles and use [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html) to accomplish goals, I think.

Comment: @VladimirBotka , could you possibly rephrase your comment as an answer so I'll be able to mark it as a solution? I used the hyperlinks you provided and this helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: @NR: Because of "put on hold" no more answers are allowed. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A role can have tasks and templates and other tools defined that are not actually referenced by it's main.yml. Whether that is a good idea or not is an argument left to the individual. We find it helpful.

For example, we have an app that requires a DB edit which made more sense to put in our DB role where the tools live, rather than in the app-install role which has none of them. No other app uses that task file, so it's only called by the app-install playbook, not the role itself.

Our roles are all individual repos submodule'd into a playbook-specific repo where the site.yml, ansible.cfg and supporting scripts live. The DB role is submodule'd into `role/install-oradb`, which has `tasks/addProfile.yml` just for this app. We call it at the end of the siter yaml, after all the other roles have executed, with an explicit `tasks` section, like this:

```
tasks:
  # fix password expiration  -
  - name: Make ASAP user non-expiring.
    include: roles/install-oradb/tasks/addProfile.yml
```